# How are these two methods to find what power of 2 a number is, different?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitmask

So, let's say I have a number `N` that's guaranteed to be a power of 2 and is always greater than 0. Now, I wrote two C methods to find what power of 2 `N` is, based on bitwise operators -

Method A -

```
int whichPowerOf2(long long num) {
    int ret = -1;
    while (num) {
        num >>= 1;
        ret += 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Method B -

```
int whichPowerOf2(long long num) {
    int idx = 0;
    while (!(num & (1<<idx))) idx += 1;
    return idx;
}
```

Intuitively, the two methods seem one and the same and also return the same values for different (smaller) values of `N`. However, Method B doesn't work for me when I try to submit my solution to a coding problem.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? Why is Method A right and Method B wrong?

Comment: Probable hint: I believe the type of this expression: `1<<idx` is `int`.

Comment: Wouldn't the second one loop forever for `num=0` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. You're right, forgot to mention num's always >= 2. Edited.

Comment: Change `(1<<idx)` to `(1ULL<<idx)`

Comment: I would also change `num` to be `unsigned`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Bounds of the problem allow `num` in the range of long long. But, thanks anyway, found the issue after your comments.

Comment: @gravetii You work with positive numbers, so there is no reason to have signed types. Moreover, you really don't want to deal with undefined/implementation defined behaviors when you shift something into the sign bit.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you're saying. It makes perfect sense. I was actually just solving a problem on an online judge and I happened to use long long for it. That's all. Point taken though - when only doing bitwise operations like this, better use unsigned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this subexpression:

```
1<<idx
```

The constant `1` has type `int`.  If `idx` becomes larger than the bit width of an `int`, you invoked [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This is specified in section 6.5.7p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding bitwise shift operators:

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
>   of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of
>   the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width
>   of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

Change the constant to `1LL` to give it type `long long`, matching the type of `num`.

```
while (!(num & (1LL<<idx))) idx += 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Method B, the following line can cause undefined behaviour:

```c
while (!(num & (1<<idx))) idx += 1;
```

Why? Well, the expression `1<<idx` is evaluated as an `int` because the constant `1` is an `int`. Further, as `num` is a `long long` (which we'll assume has more bits than an `int`), then you could end up left-shifting by more than the number of bits in an `int`.

To fix the issue, use the `LL` suffix on the constant:

```c
while (!(num & (1LL<<idx))) idx += 1;
```

Comment: 1<<idx is int because 1 is int, not because idx is int. idx is fine as an int if you use 1LL

Comment: You really want to use `ULL` not `LL` (and all other values would be better as 'unsigned' due to undefined behavior when shifting a 1 bit into the sign bit